# How would I rewrite this snippet of jQuery to work in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

```
$("input[multiple]").click();
```

That command works fine in Chrome / Firefox but not IE, does anyone know what the cross browser equivalent of it would be?

**edit**

With thanks to @Andrew Marshall

```
alert($("input[multiple]").size())
```

returns 0.

Comment: you can try with script debugger in IE or VWD Express with IE to debug the code.

Comment: That should work. One of the major benefits of jQuery is that is is cross-browser compatible by default.

Comment: @JohnFx - that is what I thought.

Comment: If I remember correctly, IE doesn't let you attach events to individual options in, for instance, a `<select>` element.  Not sure, but this sounds related.

Comment: It's possible IE is ignoring the attribute in the DOM for some reason (standards mode?). What happens if you run `alert($("input[multiple]").size())`?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Good spot, it returns 0, other browsers return 1

Comment: What's the doctype in your HTML? Does removing/changing it help?

Comment: Doctype is html5, so `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Just an FYI, `multiple` is not a valid HTML5 attribute for input. You can use `data-multiple`, though. Can you run `alert(document.getElementById("inputElementsIdHere").attributes.toString());` (replacing with the actual ID of the input element with the multiple attribute)? If multiple isn't included there, it's IE, if it is, it's jQuery's fault.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-multiple

Comment: @akira I had been testing it in the validator with type="text", which makes the multiple attribute invalid, so I guess it can only be used with certain types, which makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least I do not see any 'multiple' attribute at the `<input`> tag for old html:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

that attribute looks like something new in html5:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-multiple

which IE are you using? does it support html5? does it just fallback to html4? i checked IE6, IE7 and IE8 on http://html5test.com and neither of them supports the 'multiple' attribute at the `<input>` tag.

Comment: I have tested in both IE7 and IE8 both with the same effect.  This sounds like it could be the issue, I am going to try selecting the element based on something else to confirm.